# slide in contact form - help please

Tags: jquery, contacts, contact-form

trying to get this contact form to work properly, the form slides out from a hidden div, which seem to work fine, but close upon submiting the form, which is what i want but it closes even if the form fields are empty. if fields are filed it and submit it closes before get confirmation.

demo here http://g-thos.com

```
<section id="" class="contact contact-wrap">

<section class="wrap social-info intro contact about">


  <section role="contact-form" id="contact-form">
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$error = "";

if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
$error .= "You didn't type in your name. <br />";
}

if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
  if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){ 
  $error .= "The e-mail address you entered is not valid. <br/>";
  }
} else {
$error .= "You didn't type in an e-mail address. <br />";
}

if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
$message = $_POST['message'];
} else {
$error .= "You didn't type in a message. <br />";
}

if(($_POST['code']) == $_SESSION['code']) { 
$code = $_POST['code'];
} else { 
$error .= "The captcha code you entered does not match. Please try again. <br />";    
}

if (empty($error)) {
$from = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>';
$to = "myemail@email";
$subject = "New contact form message";
$content = $name . " has sent you a message: \n" . $message;
$success = "<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent!</p>";
mail($to,$subject,$content,$from);
}
}
?>
  <h2>Getin Touch</h2>
  <div id="note"><?php
  if (!empty($error)) {
  echo '<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/> The following error(s) returned:</strong><br/>' . $error . '</p>';
  } elseif (!empty($success)) {
  echo $success;
  }
?></div><!--end note-->
      <form method="post" id="contact">
        <div class="input-wrap">
          <div class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" value="<?php if ($_POST['name']) { echo $_POST['name']; } ?>" class="required" id="name" />
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if ($_POST['email']) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" class="required email" id="email" />
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="subject" name="subject" id="subject" value="<?php if ($_POST['subject']) { echo $_POST['subject']; } ?>" class="required" id="subject" />
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <textarea rows="8" placeholder="message" name="message" id="message" style="height: 50px;"><?php if ($_POST['message']) { echo $_POST['message']; } ?></textarea>
          </div>
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/includes/js/captcha.php"> <input type="text" placeholder="code" name="code"></p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
      </form>
  </section>
  <div class="clear"></div>

</section>
</section>

$(document).ready(function(){

//animation for same page links #
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
        if ($(this.hash).length) {
            $(this).click(function(event) {
                var targetOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
                var target = this.hash;
                event.preventDefault();            
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 500);
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
});


$('#nav li a.contact, #content a#contact-link').click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    $('.contact-wrap').slideToggle();

    if(contentStatus == 'visible') {

        $('#content, section.featured').fadeTo('normal', 0.2);

        contentStatus = 'hidden';

    } else {

        $('#content, section.featured').fadeTo('normal', 1);

        contentStatus = 'visible';

    }

    return false;

});

$('#content, footer').click(function() {

    $('#nav li a.contact').removeClass('selected');
    $('.contact-form').slideUp();
    $('#content, section.featured').fadeTo('normal', 1);
    contentStatus = 'visible';

});

});
```

Comment: Looks a bit like a mess TBH. Why not use some front-end validation before sending anything to the server? You can try [Ideal Forms](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) or [jQuery Validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for example. Then do an AJAX request to re-validate on the server. Both these plugins have ajax shortcuts to do this very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Front end validation would be best, something like (if you dont feel like pulling in a full featured validator like elclanrs suggested):

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  if ($('textarea[name="name"]', this).val() == '') {
    e.preventDefault();
    errorMessage("You didn't type in your name. <br />");
  }

  // ... repeat for the rest of your fields
});

function errorMessage(error) {
  $('#note').html('<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/> The following error(s) returned:</strong><br/>' + error + '</p>');
}
```

Or you could edit your php to show the form by default on page load if there are errors.

```
if (!empty($error)) {
  // show contact form
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply have tested your method and this work, thak you very much. appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Quite frankly, your code makes me want to curl up into a fetal postion and go to sleep. And by that i mean, dear god separate your html, php, and javascript into different files...

now that this unpleasantry is out of the way...

1. Use this [**validation plugin**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).
2. Put this property in the required fields of your html `requred="true"`
3. Add this logic into your JS at the appropriate point.

---

```
if(!$("form").isValid()){
  return false;
} else {
  // do animation
}
```

Comment: thank you for you comment, i do realize that my code is a little messy, and is working to correct that, thank you for you input.

Comment: i appreciate and take on board what others say, and try to or do my best to do better, definitely will take the time out to clean up my code and make my designs better. thank you and good night/day to you all.